# document.querySelector to select different buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I'm not really a coder but I'm trying to use disintegrate.js and I have it working on one of the buttons on my site but I would like to have this effect work on many different classes/buttons.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".boxer");
var ctx;
var colorInfoElem = document.querySelector("#colorInfo");
html2canvas(btn).then(canvas => {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    createParticleCanvas();
    let reductionFactor = 17;
    btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
        // Get the color data for our button
        let width = btn.offsetWidth;
        let height = btn.offsetHeight
        let colorData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
        // Keep track of how many times we've iterated (in order to reduce
        // the total number of particles create)
        let count = 0;
        // Go through every location of our button and create a particle
        for (let localX = 0; localX < width; localX++) {
            for (let localY = 0; localY < height; localY++) {
                if (count % reductionFactor === 0) {
                    let index = (localY * width + localX) * 4;
                    let rgbaColorArr = colorData.slice(index, index + 4);
                    let bcr = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let globalX = bcr.left + localX;
                    let globalY = bcr.top + localY;
                    createParticleAtPoint(globalX, globalY, rgbaColorArr);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    });
});
/* An "exploding" particle effect that uses circles */
var ExplodingParticle = function() {
    // Set how long we want our particle to animate for
    this.animationDuration = 1000; // in ms
    // Set the speed for our particle
    this.speed = {
        x: -5 + Math.random() * 10,
        y: -5 + Math.random() * 10
    };
    // Size our particle
    this.radius = 5 + Math.random() * 5;
    // Set a max time to live for our particle
    this.life = 30 + Math.random() * 10;
    this.remainingLife = this.life;
    // This function will be called by our animation logic later on
    this.draw = ctx => {
        let p = this;
        if (this.remainingLife > 0 && this.radius > 0) {
            // Draw a circle at the current location
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(p.startX, p.startY, p.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.rgbArray[0] + ',' + this.rgbArray[1] + ',' + this.rgbArray[2] + ", 1)";
            ctx.fill();
            // Update the particle's location and life
            p.remainingLife--;
            p.radius -= 0.25;
            p.startX += p.speed.x;
            p.startY += p.speed.y;
        }
    }
}
var particles = [];

function createParticleAtPoint(x, y, colorData) {
    let particle = new ExplodingParticle();
    particle.rgbArray = colorData;
    particle.startX = x;
    particle.startY = y;
    particle.startTime = Date.now();
    particles.push(particle);
}
var particleCanvas, particleCtx;

function createParticleCanvas() {
    // Create our canvas
    particleCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    particleCtx = particleCanvas.getContext("2d");
    // Size our canvas
    particleCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    particleCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    // Position out canvas
    particleCanvas.style.position = "absolute";
    particleCanvas.style.top = "0";
    particleCanvas.style.left = "0";
    // Make sure it's on top of other elements
    particleCanvas.style.zIndex = "1001";
    // Make sure other elements under it are clickable
    particleCanvas.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    // Add our canvas to the page
    document.body.appendChild(particleCanvas);
}

function update() {
    // Clear out the old particles
    if (typeof particleCtx !== "undefined") {
        particleCtx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }
    // Draw all of our particles in their new location
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].draw(particleCtx);
        // Simple way to clean up if the last particle is done animating
        if (i === particles.length - 1) {
            let percent = (Date.now() - particles[i].startTime) / particles[i].animationDuration;
            if (percent > 1) {
                particles = [];
            }
        }
    }
    // Animate performantly
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="boxer"><a href="#" class="attractionslink">Attractions</a></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="boxer2"><a href="#" class="attractionslink">Safety</a></div>
</div>
```

Right now when I click boxer 1 it works but when I click boxer 2 it doesn't .  I tried adding `boxer2` to the first line of `var btn` so it looks like `var btn = document.querySelector (".boxer",".boxer2");` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

The code would go like this:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".boxer, .boxer2")
```

Now, everywhere you were using `btn` as a single element you have to change the code in order to take the value from the **array** `btn` (yes, it is an array now).

For instance, now, instead of `btn.addEventListener` you have to loop (maybe [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) over all buttons like this:

```
btn.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I think the wording is wrong on my part so currently there are no button elements on the page theyre just these divs with some css applied to and a little text inside.  I tried to implement the code you put there but I'm probably just doing it wrong.  As querySelectorAll by itself though it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @Isaac I know it can be hard this for a new user like you here on SO and since you told us you are not really a coder, but... Could you please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely we can help you better.

Comment: Cool yeah I'll try to get on that I appreciate all of your help so far though everything you say makes sense I'm just implementing it wrong most likely.

Comment: @Isaac great, you could use something like https://next.plnkr.co/, http://jsfiddle.net, https://stackblitz.com, http://codepen.io/pen for creating that [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or even [stacksnippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Isaac great you did it. Now, You should make your code in the jsfiddle exactly the same as the question code so future reader don't get lost and maybe even they can help you. Look closely and you'll see there differences from the code posted here and the one in the fiddle. Also, very important, fix this error in the code so It can run properly: `Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined` (press `F12` and you'll see it in console)

Comment: Ohhh :( Okay yeah I dont think I can fix that, its a javascript library I'm using that and disintegrate.js to get the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".boxer, .boxer2");
```

This is the exact same syntax as CSS selectors in a .css file when selecting elements for styling. You select 2 different things by separating them with a comma.

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, you need to convert it into an array and iterate over that array to add event listeners to the each node of the dom list

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.boxer,.boxer2');

[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
  console.log(btn);
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    alert(this.innerText + " Clicked!");
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxer"><a href="#" class="attractionslink">Attractions</a></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="boxer2"><a href="#" class="attractionslink">Safety</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: IMO, [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) won't work because the OP wants to add the event listener to all elements matching the selector. `querySelector` will return only the first element.

Comment: Hi so the bottom way kind of works, except it only works for .boxer and not .boxer2.  Top way doesn't seem to work thank you though.

Comment: Because querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, you need to convert it into an array and iterate over that array to add event listeners to the each node of the dom list, see my edit.

Comment: Hi there I made those changes but then i get a btn is undefined error.

Comment: You can now run my code snippet which proves my code works. Make sure you query the DOM once the elements exist on the page, not before.

Comment: Hi thanks I'm getting btn undefined on my end when I try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".boxer, .boxer2")
[].prototype.forEach.call(btn, function(button) {
  button.addEventListener // rest of the code
});
```